# Como quebrar a linha?

Tags: python, python-3.x, quebras-de-linha

```
Nome = input("Digite o nome do cliente: ")
DiaVencimento = input("Digite o dia de vencimento: ")
MêsVencimento = input("Digite o mês de vencimento: ")
ValorFatura = input("Digite o valor da fatura: ")

print("Olá,", Nome, 
"A sua fatura com vencimento em ", DiaVencimento, " de ", MêsVencimento, "no valor de R$", ValorFatura, "está fechada.")
```

Tem como quebrar a linha logo após a variável "Nome"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basta colocar o caractere de quebra de linha onde deseja a quebra.
Esse caractere é digitado escapando-se a letra "n" com uma barra invertida - a famosa sequência "\n" -  quando o parser do Python encontra essa sequência dentro de uma string ela é automaticamente convertida para o caractere de quebra de linha usado em sistemas Unix, que é universal (o "print" depois converte para a sequência correta em cada sistema operacional):

```
print("Olá,", Nome, 
"\n A sua fatura com vencimento em ", DiaVencimento, " de ", MêsVencimento, "no valor de R$", ValorFatura, "está fechada.")
```

Também não é legal ficar abrindo e fechando aspas, e mais as vírgulas toda hora - Python tem diversas possibilidades de formatação de string que permitem que você crie seu texto de saída de forma bem mais legível. Uma delas é o método ".format" de strings:

```
print("Olá {nome}\n. A sua fatura com vencimento em {vencimento} de {mesvencimento} no valor de R${valor:0.02f} está fechada".format(nome=nome, vencimento=DiaVencimento,  mesvencimento=MesVencimento, valor=float(ValorFatura)))
```

E na versão 3.6 em diante você pode até usar strings com o prefixo `f" "` que permitem a formatação direta a partir das variáveis, sem precisar chamar o método `format`. Ou seja, fica só assim:

```
print(f"Olá, {Nome}\n A sua fatura com vencimento em {DiaVencimento} de {MêsVencimento} no valor de R$ {ValorFatura} está fechada.")
```

Comment: Python permite variáveis com nomes acentuadas `MêsVencimento`? Eu jurada que isso não era permitido.

Comment: EM Python 3 pode sim  - eu pessoalmente não recomendaria, mas pode.

Answer (score 6):

Use o escape `\n`

```
print("Olá,", Nome, "\n A sua fatura com vencimento em ", DiaVencimento, " de ", MêsVencimento, "no valor de R$", ValorFatura, "está fechada.")
```